# How to query from nearest shard/replica set

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We are looking at [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and are evaluating MongoDB as our query database.  We have several branch offices with very poor internet connections (256 - 768 mbs DSL) that cannot be upgraded (remote rural locations with no ISP options).  The thought was that we could put a box running MongoDB in each branch office and use some sort of clustering so that reads would become very fast since they were accessed over the LAN.

I do not need fail over or high availability.

How do I setup MongoDB so that computers in the branch office talk to the Mongodb instance in the branch office?  Note this will be read only.

If MongoDB cannot support this workflow then I am open to suggestions for alternate document based databases that can support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a secondary to the MongoDB replica set for each geographical location. Then you can connect to each secondary directly by specifying the hostname of the mongo instance that's local to where you are connecting from, and then issue the slaveOk() command to allow it to be queried. Replication will keep the secondaries in sync with the primary as closely as possible. 
Writes/updates will still need to be handled by the primary of the replica set, however.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up.  I had read the documentation but couldn't quite nail down what an optimal configuration would be.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) was built for this: occasionally connected document databases.

You can copy a database to your laptop, take it on a plane, modify it there and when you'll have network again, you'll be able to synchronize it with master database. The same works for remote offices.

I strongly suggest that you check it out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  We looked at CouchDB also but MongoDB's update in place technology fit our use case better than CouchDB's MVCC technology.  We are still tied to a traditional RDBMS for our command (write) database due to other legacy applications so occasional connection is not an option for us.